# Setting column width in html & making table fit screen

Tags: python, html, html-table

I am editing html code produced by difflib using beautiful soup.

The html code produces a table. Initially the table would be too big, but I updated the html like so:

```
differencehtml = re.sub("table cellpadding=\"0\"", "table cellpadding=\"0\" style = \"table-layout:fixed\" width = \"100%\"", differencehtml)
```

Adding the style and width specifications made the table fit the screen (hurrah!), but it also made all columns have the same width.

I tried adding this code to specify the width of each column:

```
differencehtml = re.sub("td class=\"diff_next\"", "td class=\"diff_next\" width = \"5%\"", differencehtml)
differencehtml = re.sub("td class=\"diff_header\"", "td class=\"diff_header\" width = \"5%\"", differencehtml)
differencehtml = re.sub("td nowrap=\"nowrap\"", "td style = \"word-wrap: break-word\" width = \"40%\"", differencehtml)
```

but it had no impact. (side note - those column widths add up to 50%, but each of these td's appears twice in each row so it does add up to 100%)

How can I set the column width?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I need to be editing the th element, not td.
Useful info here: https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/